# How to get current user key when log in

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

How do i get the current user key who has log in. I have tried this way.

```
openMapPage()
  {
   var ref = firebase.database().ref("request");
    ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => { // <------ Here!
        var a = snapshot.exists();  // true
        var c = snapshot.hasChild("reqdetails"); // true
        var d = snapshot.child('reqdetails').exists();
        var requestsKey = snapshot.key;
        var requestsValue = snapshot.val();

          this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data =>{
      this.profileData = this.af.object(data.uid);
                console.log(this.profileData);
    })
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => { // <------ And here!
            var requestKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var requestValue = childSnapshot.val();

            var reqdetails = requestValue.reqdetails;
            if (reqdetails) {
                this.data = requestKey;
                console.log(this.data);
                //this.arr.push(requestKey);
                //console.log(this.arr);

                 this.getRequest = this.angFire.list('request', {
                   query: {
                   orderByChild: 'reqdetails',
                   startAt: 'reqdetails'
            }
         }) 


            }
        });

    });     
  }
```

I have tried getting the current user at this part of the code:

```
 this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data =>{
      this.profileData = this.af.object(data.uid);
                console.log(this.profileData);
    })
```

When i console log for profileData i am getting this thing:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Javascript` you can get the `onAuthStateChanged()` callback when user is logged in or logged out using firebase.

To get the currentUser key you can use:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var currentUserKey = firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

I hope it will help.

For more detail refer: [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)